# google docs wysiwyg editor opensource

Tags: wysiwyg, google-docs

I remember earlier this month or last month, perhaps it was during google i/o, but there was some mention of google open sourcing their wysiwyg editor, not the one that's dependent on execCommand, I think that one is in closure, but the one which they built using all custom JS to control everyone from cursors to uh, everything custom.

Does anyone know if this really was released or am I just dreaming? Thanks.

Comment: I sure hope it's released.  contentEditable/execCommand support is non-existent or a total failure on mobile browsers so far.  In the meantime, I'm reverse engineering the Google Docs editing surface and layout engine with HttpFox and http://jsbeautifier.org/  >> https://docs.google.com/static/document/client/js/3684604164-v2-kix_main_i18n_kix_core.js